# python script to insert into MySQL database - special symbols - unicode : search and store

Tags: php, python, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I would like to know what is the best strategy to encode symblols such as \alpha into a MySQL data base and effectively query it.

I create my MySQL tables with "CHARSET=utf8".

```
import mysql.connector
import urllib
import re
from mysql.connector import errorcode
Connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='XXXX', password='XXXX', unix_socket="mysql.sock")
Cursor = Connection.cursor()
Cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
            `test_string` text NOT NULL,
            `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
            UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
            ''')
 xml = unicode(urllib.urlopen('http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pmc&id=2174229').read(),'utf-8')
 Cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `test_string`) VALUES ('''+"001"+", '"+re.escape(xml).encode("utf-8")+"');")
```

Next when encoding strings, before inserting them into the MySQL database I ensure to encode them into utf8 using ".encode("utf-8")" and when inserting I ensure to escape the string using "re.escape" before inserting.

Next I go into phpMyAdmin to look at the data rows, For instance

The original string is

```
"generating the α- and β-APP",
```

After Insertion, In the database I can see it as

```
"generating the &#945;- and &#946;-APP"
```

However, if I display after querying for rows containing "generating the" from the database on a html page, the symbol α and β are displayed correctly on the HTML page. I am confused.

Why is it so? A related question I have is that, Now if I have to query the MySQL database for these special symbols(α,β etc) how do I do that? Please pardon if I missed any obvious issues.

Comment: share some code with us :>

Comment: I cannot paste the whole code for it is too long, I have tried to capture the essence of the issue. Please have a look

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, Finally the issue was that the special characters were somehow converted to HTML codes. So, this did the trick

```
import HTMLParser
h= HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
h.unescape(test_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
(user='XXXX', password='XXXX', unix_socket="mysql.sock",charset='utf8',use_unicode=True)
```

and go to phpmyadmin and change the collation utf8_general_ci.